# How can I package my ng-cli app for redistribution via NPM?

Tags: angular

As the title states, I'm looking for 'best practices' or guides on how to go about packaging your application created via angular-cli for redistribution via NPM.

The way I was thinking would be to have my main app as its own repository, but include the modules I wanted to reuse as git submodules, this however doesn't seem like the best way to handle it, as users who install the submodule for extension don't have access to the core boostrapping of the application. I also don't want third party developers to necessarily *have* to learn git submodules, as they can be a bit tricky.

Edit: 
The folder structure is currently

```
/
src/
   app/
       core/ # main module
       shared/ # shared modules used by core
       ui/ # UI module specifically for general UI components
```

The modules, core, shared and UI are what I want bundled into one application that developers can simply npm install & import into their existing project.

Any ideas?

Comment: It would be nice to explain what kind of 'application' is under discussion.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by 'what kind of application'? I'm not sure of the relevance or how to explain. It's the base application generated with `ng new` but with three main modules I'll want to package for redistribution.

Comment: The way how the app is supposed to be used may affect the way how it can be redistributed. Any details will help. The answer on how to redistribute 'some' app is 'somehow' - which is likely not the answer you're looking for.

Comment: I want people to be able to do, `yarn install my-package --save` and start using the libraries immediately. I have three modules, but only the core will be used while the other two are support modules. So baiscally, you'll install the app via yarn/npm and be able to start using the modules, e.g `imports: [MyModule.forRoot(customProvider)]`

Comment: So are they libraries or apps? It's really not clear what you're asking about. A simplified folder structure and simplified code for both third-party and first-party apps are necessary to understand your case. The question will likely fall into 'opinion based' category (which is not allowed on SO) any way, but in its current state it has no chance.

Comment: It's one app, multiple modules, as stated before. I will refrain from using the term library to avoid confusion. I've created the modules within an angular-cli project, the modules I've created are what I want to redistribute. It would make no sense to have uesrs git clone my project and use that as a skeleton when they can simply include and make use of the modules. How to package them for redistribution is my question.

Comment: For *module* redistribution it really doesn't matter if you developed it with ng-cli or not. It is user's choice if he/she wishes to use ng-cli. Take a look at well-known third-party A2 libraries.

Comment: I have looked at external modules and ones that were made with the cli normally have you clone the project and npm install, forcing you to start off with their skeleton. Third party specific libs are all top level and aren't made with the same concept of using the platformbrowser or application bootstrapping, hence the question. I have updated my question outlining the directory structure and kind of cleared up what I want.

Comment: You're confusing a library and an app. A library will never require the one clone a project, this would be nonsense. If you want to make a boilerplate skeleton, make it a repo to clone. To make it several libraries publish the modules separately to NPM. Sorry, without knowing what 'shared modules' and 'UI module' exactly mean it's not possible to suggest anything useful.

Comment: I think you're just confused on what I'm wanting and focusing on the wrong part of the goal. I'll wait and see if somebody who can understand will shed some light. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functionality I desire has yet to been implemented:

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1692

All the workarounds only seem to cover only some of what I want and don't let you develop your base application with the CLI.

Workaround projects:

http://dbarnes.me/writing-an-aot-compliant-angular-library/

https://github.com/filipesilva/angular-quickstart-lib

https://medium.com/@cyrilletuzi/how-to-build-and-publish-an-angular-module-7ad19c0b4464